# Aligning button to right of Login in nav bar

Tags: material-ui

I am creating a navigation menu and part of it is having a Login link and "Try for Free" button on the right part of the webpage. But what is puzzling me is how to get the button aligned to the right of the Login link. Currently it looks like this:

[image: Login and button]

What am I doing wrong?

```
<Grid item xs={4}>
  {/* <Toolbar disableGutters> */}
  <Tabs className={classes.tabContainer}>
    <Tab className={classes.tab} component={Link} to="/analyze" label="Login" />
  </Tabs>
  {/* <Typography className={classes.root}>
  <Link href="#" onClick={menuOptions}>
    Link
  </Link>
</Typography> */}
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="default"
    size="medium"
    // style={{ marginTop: '1.1em' }}
    // style={{ maxWidth: '108px', minWidth: '108px' }}
    onClick={() => {
      // handleClickImportPGN();
    }}
  >
    Try for Free
  </Button>
  {/* </Toolbar> */}
</Grid>;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `button aligned to the right of the Login link`?

Comment: The button is currently below Login. I want it to the right of login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One of the handiest ways is to use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)**

```
<Grid item style={{ display: "flex" }}>
  <Tabs>
    <Tab component={Link} label="Login" />
  </Tabs>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="default"
    size="medium"
    // style={{ marginTop: '1.1em' }}
    // style={{ maxWidth: '108px', minWidth: '108px' }}
    onClick={() => {
      // handleClickImportPGN();
    }}
  >
    Try for Free
  </Button>
  {/* </Toolbar> */}
</Grid>;
```

But if you want to make use more of Material UI, you could try to have a few more Grid within each of the children elements.

**Simplified Working Example:**

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: I've just added the flex styling, but now my button is taking up the full height of the header area. Any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: How would you like them to be? To have some extra spaces around them?

Comment: Well, in my sales page, the button is a similar height to the Add comment button on stackOverflow. You can see the height of it in my image on my main post. But for some reason, when I used the flex styling, it not only moves the button to the right, but also increased the height.

Comment: I updated the sandbox, you could add `align-items: flex-start;` or `align-items: flex-end;` to make it align to the top or bottom of your header.

Comment: That reduced the height of the button now. Last bit is for me to vertically align the Login and Button to the center of the header. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use `alignItems: "center"` instead. I updated the sanbox